# MySQL AUTO INCREMENT vs. ID generada desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo tablas las cuales tendrán millones de registros en ellas. Cuál es la mejor forma de crear el ID único de esas tablas?

Según MySQL, está el uso AUTO_INCREMENT, pero a cierto número de registros se hace más lento cada vez.

En el caso de generacion de ID desde PHP tengo el siguiente código:

```
private function crearIdentificacion(){
    $min = 1;
    $max = 0;
    switch(PHP_INT_SIZE) {
        case 4:
            $max = 2147483648;
            break;
        case 8:
            $max = 9223372036854775807;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    $diferencia   = bcadd(bcsub($min,$max),1);
        $rand_percent = bcdiv(mt_rand(), mt_getrandmax(), 8);
        return abs(bcadd($min, bcmul($diferencia, $rand_percent, 8), 0));
}
```

La cual crea un ID y su tamaño depende de si es 32bit o 64bit, pero estoy en la duda. Porque sé que cuando una tabla contiene demasiada informacion es cada vez más lento el acceso a la misma.

Comment: Recuerda que con el código PHP que muestras el ID será un número generado aleatoriamente, por lo que podrían dar colisiones. El mecanismo de AUTO_INCREMENT de MySQL genera un ID secuencial, el cual no causa colisiones. En versiones modernas MySQL utiliza una tabla de estado para generar los nuevos ID, por lo que no hay un impacto de "lentitud" cuando hay muchos registros. También influyen en la velocidad de inserción que tipo de motor de tablas se está usando (MyISAM, InnoDB, etc), si se están particionando, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pudieras tambien generar un [GUID](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php) con PHP

```
$id = com_create_guid();
```

O insertar el [GUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) directamente en MySQL

```
insert tabla (id, ...) values (UUID(), ...)
```

Comment: Qué tanta posibilidad hay de que se repita la ID? O no se repite, perdona si ando desubicado. +1 por primera respuesta.

Comment: Pues los GUID se generan de acuerdo al timestamp del procesador, es practicamente imposible que se repitan, pero creo que una vez lei que cada tantos años sucede un bug por un error de reloj que tienen los procesadores modernos (me parece que el proximo esta estimado que suceda como en el 2054).

Comment: Sucederá en el 2038. Y otra cosa, de cuántos caracteres saldrá?

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Acá una discusión interesante sobre el tema (en inglés): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid

Comment: @MáximaAlekz por lo general los GUID se generan en el formato `6ccd780c-baba-1026-9564-5b8c656024db` (30 caracteres omitiendo los guiones)

Comment: Gracias por el dato, no recordaba el año con exactitud.

Comment: Agregando al dato del 2038, es un problema que afecta sólo a sistemas que crean el tiempo basados en el método usado por sistemas UNIX y que utilizen una precisión de enteros con signo de 32 bits (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). En las versiones actuales de MySQL y PHP (5.7 y 7 respectivamente), este problema no está presente.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes tu mismo crear la llave, este ejemplo que te dejo, no se repite. Tu puedes dar la longitud que tu desee. El ejemplo solo se limita a 9999 diarios pero tu lo puedes hacer como desees.

Para que no se te haga lento a la hora de la búsqueda, solo tienes que colocar en el campo de la tabla mysql el index.

```
     $resultset = $this->db->query("SELECT Max(campo_llave) AS llave FROM nombre_tabla");
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultset);
     $datecodetable = substr($row['llave'], 0,6);
     $codem = substr($row['llave'], -4);
     if(date("ymd") > $datecodetable){
         $codem = "0000";
     }
     $codem++;

     switch(strlen($codem)){
         case 1: $codem = "000$codem"; break;
         case 2: $codem = "00$codem"; break;
         case 3: $codem = "0$codem"; break;
         case 4: $codem = "$codem"; break;
     }
     $code = "".(date('ymd'))."$codem";
```

Comment: +1, Es una respuesta interestante, ademas de diferente :)