# ¿Que criterio usar para la generación de código de producto?

Tags: diseño, patrones-de-diseño

¿Que criterios usan para generar el código de producto?
Estuve pensando en por ejemplo establecer un rango de 0 a 1000 y construir una función random que elija un número al azar asignándoselo a cada producto que ingrese. Pero también he leído sobre códigos alfanuméricos como por ejemplo:

```
Nombre:                           Código:
Remera Blanca Manga Corta         RBMC2103
Pantalon Jean                     PJAA2134
```

En fin, ¿que criterio se utiliza para la generación de código de producto?
Quedaría realmente muy mal si tomo como código a su identificador (id) en la base de datos, ya que empezaría en 1 y la verdad es que muy bien no queda.

Desde ya, muchas gracias

Comment: Encontré esta [respuesta _en inglés_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39259742/4092887) que tal vez te pueda ayudar. Lee bien la respuesta.

Comment: crea un id  y un codigo unico, a este tiene dos opciones 1. que el usuario lo coloque el 2. genera un codigo hexadecimal random bien sea por db o por progama

Comment: porque no dejas el SKU propio del producto?, un id autonumeric y el sku....

Comment: Puedes hacer el código según tu desees, si el producto tiene código de barra puedes usar ese como ID. Lo otro es que lo puedes generar tu mismo el código de acuerdo a tus necesidades. Te dejo un link donde publique como generar un ID, que lo puedes usar como código.  (http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/mysql-auto-increment-vs-id-generada-desde-php/60419#60419)

Answer (score 1):

Un código de producto tiene el máximo sentido si se compone de circulos de numeros o caracteres con un sentido definido. Un ejemplo:

```
00-000-00-0000-(K1) - modificadores opcionales
|  |   |   +----- producto individual
|  |   +--------- categoría de producto
|  +------------- empresa productora del producto
+---------------- pais de origen
```

Es tema complejo de eligir un sistema de numeración apto para manejar las información es que tu logistíca requiere, pero quizás con ejemplo te entra una idéa por donde deberías empezar de diseñar la estructura de tu código de productos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola podrías hacerlo (usar el id como identificador no le veo problema y en base si se puede seria efectivo) ahora segundo también podrías asignarle un código secundario digamos para identificación de producto asignando un código numérico o alfanumerico que se pueda imprimir en algun formato de código de barras y pegarselo al producto fisico para su facil lectura.

En el caso que quieras solo generar un codigo unico una alternativa es usar un  [UUID](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_%C3%BAnico_universal) en la web hay varias implementaciones segun el lenguaje que uses. En todo caso siempre manten el ID si puede como clave primaria y usa el codigo generado como identificador.

Otra alternativa boba, calculale la suma SHA al id y úsalo de código.

Hay miles de forma de implementarlo dependera de muchos factores. Deberias explicar el uso que le quieres dar.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

yo no usaría el ID de producto, por lo menos de forma directa, como código del mismo de cara al público porque estas exponiendo un dato de la BD.

En cuanto a que usar, lo primero sería determinar la longitud del código de producto, por ejemplo 7, lo que puede venir de la lógica de tu aplicación y del número de productos a manejar. Luego utilizar códigos alfanuméricos puede ser interesante, en los cuales las letras puedan darte alguna información sobre el producto, nada que sea sensible, pero que pueda ayudar a la hora de gestionar stocks, envíos, etc. al personal que va a manipular los productos si estos son físicos. Por ejemplo un producto que entra en stock en Enero de 2017 y que no puede estar ahí más de 9 meses podría ser: en17yi9, donde:

```
en -> sería enero
17 -> se refiere al año
yi -> son letras aleatorias
9  -> los meses máximos en stockage
```

Lleva algo de lógica de negocio este código como ves y ayudaría a su gestión en almacén. Todo depende un poco de lo que manejes, pero por "utilidad" los códigos no suelen ser enteramente aleatorios.

Saludos.